# Undocumented Mac Calls

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm working on a couple of mac products, and in order to do what I need to do, I'm using some calls to undocumented methods on Mac Classes. Like

IKImageView's

```
 doRotate:(id)
```

and

PDFDocument's

```
(NSPrintOperation *)getPrintOperationForPrintInfo:(NSPrintInfo *)printInfo autoRotate:(BOOL)doRotate;
```

How dangerous is it to use methods like these? Is there a danger other than that Apple will make them no-longer available in some future rev?

Comment: You've asked enough questions, you should have learned how to format them by now ;-)

Comment: @Joachim: I do, I just thought that a list of function names wasn't code that needed to be formatted... B-)

Comment: it's not absolutely necessary, but they are usually much easier to read, when they are formatted. But maybe that's just me, so feel free to ignore me.

Answer (score 7):

It's not altogether unheard-of, but if you're going to use them in release software, you need to make absolutely sure you have your shit together and test every version of OS X extensively before it comes out — because yes, Apple could do any number of things in a future revision (change the method's signature, remove the method, introduce some subtle bug in the method that works in all of *their* use cases).

At any rate, if you find there's something you can't do with the existing API, you should file an enhancement request with Apple so they know it's something they need to add.

Comment: Ok, I'd already done that for 2 of them... And I've gotten no response... I just submitted another for the most recent one I found...

Answer (score 4):

To extract an interface you can use the [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) utility which will give you a nice auto-generated header file of any MachO file. For example, to find `getPrintOperationForPrintInfo` method you can use the command:

```
$ class-dump /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/PDFKit | fgrep getPrintOperationForPrintInfo
```

Which will give you:

```
- (id)getPrintOperationForPrintInfo:(id)arg1 autoRotate:(BOOL)arg2;
```